# Awk to check if value of column1 from file 1 is present in file2 and update field in another column

Tags: linux, shell, perl, awk, scripting

Request your help.
Need to do the below task in linux with awk.
I have two file.
I need to check if any documentN(column1) value from file 1 is also present in file2 in column1(Billdoc) and if found, then corresponding to this BillDoc value in file 2, if we have Curr(column2) value as other than INR, then in file 1 need to replace supply type(column2) as EXPWT against that documentN value in file 1.

For example we have value 262842964 in both file1 and file2 and against that value in file2 to we have Curr(column2) value as USD(which is NON INR). So i need to replace the column2(supplytype) value which is CAN in file 1 with EXPWT.

**File 1**

```
DocumentN   SupplyType

262842964          CAN

E08/1002/00798        TAX

E08/1002/00816        TAX

INDTR1117GSM1459      CAN

INDTR1117GSM5530      TAX

262852823             TAX
```

**File 2**

```
BillDoc         Curr

 262881626      INR 

 262881627      INR 

 262842964      USD

 262881629      INR

 E08/1002/00816     USD

 INDTR1117GSM5530    USD
```

Comment: Please wrap your samples in code tags and let us know on same then.

Comment: Have done..Please check now

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @as7951, please post expected output too in your post in code tags.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { if(FNR!=1&&$2!="INR") arr[$1]=1; next}
 FNR!=1 && $0 && $1 in arr  { $2="EXPWT" }
 1;' file2 file1
```

result is

```
DocumentN   SupplyType

262842964 EXPWT

E08/1002/00798        TAX

E08/1002/00816 EXPWT

INDTR1117GSM1459      CAN

INDTR1117GSM5530 EXPWT

262852823             TAX
```

I assume you just want to update the 2nd fields of records in file1, where it has `non-IND` currency in file2, to `EXPWT`

$0 in `FNR!=1 && $0 && $1 in arr`, is to take consideration of empty lines

as @kvantour answered you may use `sub($2,"EXPWT")` to retain the original field separator, but make sure the first field doesn't contain the string of second field

Comment: @as7951 btw, be careful of the another answer, it will print extra lines

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to :

- If column 1 in file1 is in column 1 in file2, then replace column 2 in file1 with `EXPWT` if and only if column 2 in file2 is not `INR`.

So the idea is to store `file2` in an array `a` indexed by `$1`. We do not store all values, but only then ones where `$2 != "INR"`. When `file2` is fully indexed, we can process `file1` by just checking if the key `$1` is in `a`. If so, you do the replace. This translates as:

```
awk '(NR==FNR)&&(FNR>1)&&($2!="INR") {a[$1]=1; next}
     (FNR==1){print;next}
     ($1 in a) { $2="EXPWT" }
     1' file2 file1
```

If you want to keep the spacing identical, you can replace `$2="EXPWT"` by `sub($2,"EXPWT")`

Comment: @kvantour..thank you very much..
i believe solution provided by you will run without any error..
May be i require your help for one more query..thanks a ton once again

Comment: @as7951 be aware that I assumed no empty lines in any file. You might have to add an extra check for that.